# How do I plot a plane EM wave?

Tags: graphics, physics, visualization

I would like to display an electromagnetic (EM) wave.  I have written code that works, but it does not "shade" the area between the graph and the axes.  Both the `Filling` and `EdgeForm` commands are ignored.

```
strength = 2; frequency = 3;

wave1 = ParametricPlot3D[{t (x/6.28), -strength Sin[frequency t (x/6.28)], 0}, 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle->Directive[Thickness[.007], Lighter[Red, .5], Filling -> Axis]];
wave2 = ParametricPlot3D[{t (x/6.28), 0, strength Sin[frequency t(x/6.28)]}, 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.007], Lighter[Blue, .5], Filling -> Axis]];

Show[wave1, wave2, Graphics3D[EdgeForm[Pink], wave1],
  Graphics3D[EdgeForm[LightBlue], wave2], 
  Axes->False, Boxed->False, PlotRange->All, ImageSize->{500, 400}]
```

I would like to accomplish filling the portion between the two sinusoidal waves and the direction of propagation of the wave with color.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a variation of the plane wave rendering done in rm -rf's answer. Here, I use arrows instead of lines to indicate the wave's displacement from the axis:

```
waveDiagram[xm_, col_, k_] := Flatten[First[
    Normal[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, xm}, Mesh -> Full, 
                PlotStyle -> Directive[col, Arrowheads[Small]]]] /. 
           Point[{x_, y_}] :> 
             If[Chop[Abs[y]] < 0.1, Point[{x, 0}], Arrow[{{x, 0}, {x, y}}]]]] /. 
          v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ] && Length[v] == 2 :> Insert[v, 0, k]

Graphics3D[(* axes *)
           {{Gray, {Arrowheads[.02], 
            Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {9 π/2, 0, 0}}]}, {Arrowheads[.01 {-1, 1}], 
            Arrow[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}]}}, 
           waveDiagram[4 π, Darker[Blue], 2], 
           waveDiagram[4 π, Darker[Green], 3]},
           Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}]
```

[image: plane wave diagram]

As a variation, here's a depiction of the circular polarization of a plane wave:

```
Show[
     (* circularly polarized wave *)
     Normal[ParametricPlot3D[{t, -Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4 π}, Mesh -> Full, 
            PlotStyle -> Directive[Darker[Blue], Arrowheads[Small]]]] /. 
     Point[{x_, y_, z_}] :> 
           If[Chop[Norm[{y, z}]] < 0.1, Point[{x, 0, 0}], 
              Arrow[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}}]],
     (* axes *)
     Graphics3D[{{Gray, {Arrowheads[.02], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {9 π/2, 0, 0}}]},
                 {Arrowheads[.01 {-1, 1}], Arrow[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}], 
                  Arrow[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}]}}}],
                Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: circular polarization]

---

The common theme in both diagrams is the use of the `Mesh` option of the plotting functions, which generates `Point[]`s on the curve(s) at preset locations. From here, we replace each `Point[]` object generated with an `Arrow[]` whose head has the coordinates of the original `Point[]`; how the position of the tail is determined depends on the plot being done.

Comment: I think the E and B fields have the wrong direction in the top figure.  The cross product k X E should point along B.

Comment: @pjg, the figure was not intended to actually designate one wave as $\mathbf B$ and the wave orthogonal to it as $\mathbf E$; it merely demonstrates how to render two waves orthogonal to each other with arrows using `Graphics3D[]`. Of course, for actual figures where each wave in the depiction carries a physical meaning, more care is necessary.

Comment: How did you get the line above the arrows in blue and green? My plot of this code doesn't show the green and blue lines above the arrows. I don't agree with the first comment, the image shows a plane wave with fields $E$ and $H$ propagating in directions transverse (perpendicular) to each other and to the direction of wave propagation (which would be the x-direction).

Comment: @Axion, it used to work in the version of *Mathematica* where I originally wrote this answer. I've edited it to something that should work in the current version.

Answer (score 23):

You've gotten answers to the specific problem you had, but here's another way of visualizing the EM wave. This is how I've always seen it depicted in my textbooks, and the advantage is that it prints neatly in black & white.

```
Module[{w1, w2, colors, plot, lines},
    w1[x_] := {x, 0, Sin[x]};
    w2[x_] := {x, Sin[x], 0};
    colors = Darker /@ {Blue, Green};

    {plot, lines} = ParametricPlot3D[{w1[x], w2[x]}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]},   
        Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
        PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Thick}, colors}\[Transpose], 
        EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{Line[{w1[x], {x, 0, 0}}], Line[{w2[x], {x, 0, 0}}]}]
        ] // Reap;

    Show[plot, 
        Graphics3D[Insert[Flatten[lines, 1], colors, 1]\[Transpose]], 
        ViewPoint -> {3.009, -1.348, 0.759}, ViewVertical -> {0.406, -0.398, 5.732}, Ticks -> None, 
        AspectRatio -> 0.75
    ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please see if my edit is okay (hope no visible colour fringing is present)

Comment: Oh that's sexy. +1

Answer (score 19):

If you use a full period for `x` you can get by with this cheap hack:

```
x = 2 Pi;

wave1 = ParametricPlot3D[{t (x/6.28), -strength Sin[
     frequency t (x/6.28)], 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Thickness[.007], Lighter[Red, .5], Filling -> Axis]];
wave2 = ParametricPlot3D[{t (x/6.28), 0, 
   strength Sin[frequency t (x/6.28)]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Thickness[.007], Lighter[Blue, .5], Filling -> Axis]];
```

Adding `/. Line -> Polygon`

```
Show[wave1, wave2, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> {500, 400}] /. Line -> Polygon
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

My take on the hatched shading version:

```
strength = 1; frequency = 3; x = 5;

pts1 =
 Table[
   {t (x/6.28), -strength Sin[frequency t (x/6.28)], 0},
   {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.03}
 ];

pts2 = {#, 0, -#2} & @@@ pts1;

Graphics3D[{
  Thickness[0.007],
  {Lighter@Red, Line[pts1]},
  {Lighter@Blue, Line[pts2]},
  Thickness[0.002],
  Pink,
  Line[ {#, # {1, 0, 1}}& /@ pts1[[;; ;; 3]] ],
  RGBColor[0.7, 0.7, 1],
  Line[ {#, # {1, 1, 0}}& /@ pts2[[;; ;; 3]] ]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

My take on arrows a la J. M.'s answer:

```
Table[{t/3, -Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi, 0.05}] //
  Graphics3D[{
    {Orange, Lighting -> "Neutral", Tube@#},
    {RGBColor[0, .8, 1], Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, 1.5 #}, 0.01] & /@
      {{3, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}},
    Arrowheads[1/40, Appearance -> "Projected"],
    Opacity[0.3],
    Arrow[{# {1, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ #[[;; ;; 3]]
  }, Boxed -> False] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 10):

You could do something like

```
strength = 2; frequency = 3; x = 5;

wave1 = ParametricPlot3D[{t (x/6.28), -s strength Sin[
      frequency t (x/6.28)], 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {s, 0, 1}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Lighter[Red, .5]];
wave2 = ParametricPlot3D[{t (x/6.28), 0, 
    s strength Sin[frequency t (x/6.28)]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {s, 0, 1}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Lighter[Blue, .5]];

Show[wave1, wave2, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> {500, 400}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that you can also combine the two waves in one `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
waves = ParametricPlot3D[
  {{t (x/6.28), -s strength Sin[frequency t (x/6.28)], 0},
   {t (x/6.28), 0, s strength Sin[frequency t (x/6.28)]}},
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {s, 0, 1},
  Mesh -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {Lighter[Red, .5], Lighter[Blue, .5]},
  PlotPoints -> {50, 2},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
  ]
```

Answer (score 6):

To get a cleaner output I would recommend taking control of the polygons in your plot more explicitly. If you rely on `ParametricPlot3D`, that control is harder to achieve.

Here is a function that plots an integer number of wavelengths with an arrow indicating the propagation direction, and blue face color for the electric field (red for magnetic field).

```
plotWave[λ_, nλ_, aspect_: 1/5] := 
  Module[{nStep = 40, amplitudes},
   amplitudes =
    Table[
     {aspect λ nλ Sin[2 Pi z/λ], 0, z},
     {z, 0, λ nλ, λ/nStep/2}
     ];
   Graphics3D[
    {
     {Black, Thick, 
      Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, λ nλ*1.08}}]},
     {FaceForm[Red],
      Polygon[Partition[amplitudes, nStep + 1, nStep]]}, {FaceForm[
       Blue], Polygon[
       Partition[amplitudes.RotationMatrix[Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}], 
        nStep + 1, nStep]]
      }}]];
plotWave[1, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first argument is the wavelength, the second argument the number of full wavelength to plot. An optional third argument can be given to specify what ratio of the longitudinal plot length should be assigned to the transverse amplitude.

The output looks pretty much the same as in the other answers, but I generate the wave from a discrete list of points at which the amplitude is calculated. It's important to do this symmetrically so that each half wave has a start and end point on the axis.

The trick then is to make a `Polygon` out of each half wave. To get the end points to lie on the axis, I partition the amplitude list (`amplitudes`) with the appropriate sub-list size (`nStep +1`). Since consecutive half waves share a point on the axis, I have to add an offset as the third argument in `Partition`.

Finally, I use the fact that `Polygon` can accept a list of lists, to make the first wave. The second wave is done the same way, except that a rotation matrix is first applied to the list `amplitudes`.

**Edit**

If you want other ideas for how to represent waves, you may want to take a look at [my web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#Arrows3D) and the `CDF` called "PlaneWaveField.cdf" linked near the bottom of the section on 3D arrows.

Comment: You can consider using [this palette](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5/12) for effortless image uploading.  I added an image to the post.

Comment: Thanks - but in this case I didn't think the image adds much info.

Answer (score 2):

The approach of Clifford algebra. The electric field is represented by ordinary vector arrow. The magnetic field is represented by disk, the area of which represents magnitude of magnetic field. By the way, normal to the disk represents the direction of (not true, i.e. axial) vector, since the magnetic field is not an ordinary vector (you cannot add electric and magnetic vectors).

```
sin = Plot[2 Sin[t], {t, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, Axes -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], Black}];

magn = Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 0.03], Circle[{\[Pi]/4, 0}, 0.3], 
    Circle[{(2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.45], Circle[{(3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.3], 
    Circle[{\[Pi] + 0, 0}, 0.03], Circle[{\[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 0}, 0.3], 
    Circle[{\[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.45], 
    Circle[{\[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.3], 
    Circle[{2 \[Pi] + 0, 0}, 0.03], 
    Circle[{2 \[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 0}, 0.3], 
    Circle[{2 \[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.45], 
    Circle[{2 \[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.3]}];

elipsesDiskai = 
  Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 0.03], Circle[{\[Pi]/4, 0}, 0.3], 
     Circle[{(2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.45], Circle[{(3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.3], 
     Circle[{\[Pi] + 0, 0}, 0.03], Circle[{\[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 0}, 0.3], 
     Circle[{\[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.45], 
     Circle[{\[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.3], 
     Circle[{2 \[Pi] + 0, 0}, 0.03], 
     Circle[{2 \[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 0}, 0.3], 
     Circle[{2 \[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.45], 
     Circle[{2 \[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, 0.3]} /. 
    Circle[x__] :> {GrayLevel[0.85], Disk[x]}];

elek = Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.036], 
    Arrow[{{\[Pi]/4, 0}, {\[Pi]/4, 2 Sin[\[Pi]/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{(2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, {(2 \[Pi])/4, 2 Sin[(2 \[Pi])/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{(3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, {(3 \[Pi])/4, 2 Sin[(3 \[Pi])/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{\[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 0}, {\[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 
       2 Sin[\[Pi] + \[Pi]/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{\[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, {\[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 
       2 Sin[\[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{\[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, {\[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 
       2 Sin[\[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{2 \[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 0}, {2 \[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 
       2 Sin[2 \[Pi] + \[Pi]/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{2 \[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 0}, {2 \[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 
       2 Sin[2 \[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{2 \[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 0}, {2 \[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 
       2 Sin[2 \[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4]}}]}];

tr[x_, y_] := 
  Polygon[{{x + 0, y - 0.1}, {x + 0.1, y + 0}, {x + 0, 
     y + 0.1}, {x + 0, y - 0.1}}];
magnArrow = 
  Graphics[{tr[\[Pi]/4, -0.29], tr[(2 \[Pi])/4, -0.45], 
    tr[(3 \[Pi])/4, -0.29], tr[\[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, 0.29], 
    tr[\[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, 0.45], tr[\[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, 0.29], 
    tr[2 \[Pi] + \[Pi]/4, -0.29], tr[2 \[Pi] + (2 \[Pi])/4, -0.45], 
    tr[2 \[Pi] + (3 \[Pi])/4, -0.29]}];

str = Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.036], Arrow[{{4.2, 1.2}, {5.2, 1.2}}]}];
kvec = Graphics[{Arrow[{{-0.1, 0}, {3 \[Pi] + 0.7, 0}}]}];
txt = Graphics[{Text[
     StyleForm["z", FontSize -> 9, 
      FontWeight -> Bold], {3 \[Pi] + 0.7, 0}, {1, 2}], 
    Text[StyleForm["k", FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 9], {4.8, 
      1.65}]}];

planeWave = 
 Show[{elipsesDiskai, kvec, sin, magn, elek, magnArrow, txt, str}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: plane wave in geometric algebra]

**Edit1**
Since plain wave polarization was not specified, I added (except the text labels) the similar picture  for elliptically polarized wave. It looks more interesting:

```
dydis = 1.6;
{h1 = 0.3*dydis, v1 = 0.7*dydis};
{h2 = 0.7*dydis, v2 = 0.3*dydis};
polinkis = 1;
poslinkis = 1.3;
tr = 0.0;

elipsesDiskai = 
  Graphics[{{GrayLevel[0.6], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, {h1 , v1}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}]}, {GrayLevel[0.9], 
     Disk[{1*poslinkis, 1*poslinkis/polinkis}, {h2 , v2}, {0, 
       2 \[Pi]}]}, {GrayLevel[0.9], 
     Disk[{2*poslinkis, 2*poslinkis/polinkis}, {h1 , v1}, {0, 
       2 \[Pi]}]}, {GrayLevel[0.6], 
     Disk[{3*poslinkis, 3*poslinkis/polinkis}, {h2 , v2}, {0, 
       2 \[Pi]}]}, {GrayLevel[0.6], 
     Disk[{4*poslinkis, 4*poslinkis/polinkis}, {h1 , v1}, {0, 
       2 \[Pi]}]}}];

elipse = ParametricPlot[{{-1/2 + t, (-1/2 + t)/
       polinkis}, {0*poslinkis + 
       h1 Cos[t], (0*poslinkis + v1 Sin[t])}, {1*poslinkis + 
       h2 Cos[t], 
      poslinkis*1/polinkis + v2  Sin[t]}, {poslinkis*2 + h1 Cos[t], 
      poslinkis*2/polinkis + v1 Sin[t]}, {poslinkis*3 + h2 Cos[t], 
      poslinkis*3/polinkis + v2 Sin[t]}, {poslinkis*4 + h1  Cos[t], 
      poslinkis*4/polinkis + 
       v1  Sin[t]}, {{-1/2 + t + 22, (-1/2 + t + 22)/polinkis}*0.12}},
     {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black, 
       Arrowheads[{{0.03, 0.2 - tr}, {0.03, 0.4 - tr}, {0.05, 
          0.6 - tr + 0.015}, {0.03, 0.8 - tr}, {0.03, 
          1 - tr}}]], {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black, 
        Arrowheads[{{-0.03, 0.1}, {-0.03, (4/(2 Pi))}}]]}, {Directive[
        AbsoluteThickness[1], Black, 
        Arrowheads[{{0.03, 0.2}, {0.03, (5/(2 Pi))}}]]}, {Directive[
        AbsoluteThickness[2], Black, 
        Arrowheads[{{0.05, 0.2}, {0.05, (4.3/(2 Pi))}}]]}, {Directive[
        AbsoluteThickness[1], Black, 
        Arrowheads[{{-0.03, 0.1}, {-0.03, (4/(2 Pi))}}]]}, {Directive[
        AbsoluteThickness[1], Black, 
        Arrowheads[{{-0.03, 0.1}, {-0.03, (4/(2 Pi))}}]]}, {Directive[
        AbsoluteThickness[2], Black]}}] /. Line[x_, ___] :> Arrow[x];

elecF = Graphics[{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1]], Arrowheads[0.03], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, v1}}], 
    Arrow[{{1*poslinkis, 
       poslinkis*1/polinkis}, {1*poslinkis + h2 Cos[t], 
        poslinkis*1/polinkis + v2  Sin[t]} /. t -> -0}], {Directive[
      AbsoluteThickness[2]], Arrowheads[0.05], 
     Arrow[{{2*poslinkis, 
        poslinkis*2/polinkis}, {2*poslinkis + h1 Cos[t], 
         poslinkis*2/polinkis + v1  Sin[t]} /. t -> -Pi/2}]}, 
    Arrow[{{3*poslinkis, 
       poslinkis*3/polinkis}, {3*poslinkis + h2 Cos[t], 
        poslinkis*3/polinkis + v2  Sin[t]} /. t -> Pi}], 
    Arrow[{{4*poslinkis, 
       poslinkis*4/polinkis}, {4*poslinkis + h1 Cos[t], 
        poslinkis*4/polinkis + v1  Sin[t]} /. t -> Pi/2}]}];

beteksto = Show[{elipsesDiskai, elipse, elecF}]
```

[image: circularly polarized electromagnetic way in geometric algebra]

Comment: Does the second plot get created with your code also?

Comment: No, I added the code for the second picture. The most important point here is the concept, not the  visualization (which was optimized for white-black print) itself