# Show[] combines my Graphics3D objects in an undesirable way

Tags: graphics, output-formatting

Thanks to those (Heike, Jens, MrWizard, and R.M.)  who helped me yesterday with figuring out how to plot an EM wave.  Now I am running into trouble with the `Show` command.  I am trying to combine three Graphics3D objects:

- a slab
- a grating, and
- a wave.

The wave is supposed to be comparable in size with the grating and it should fall on it from the top (like light would fall on a grating).  `Show` puts these together as a GIANT giant slab with grating and a puny EM wave.
The problem is that Mathematica puts all objects' coordinate axes origin to the same point.  How can I control the relative placement and sizes of these objects in `Show`?
My code follows:

```
(*
sw = slab width, sh = slab height, gw = grid width, gh = 
 grid height, cw = channel width, sl = slab length, EM1s = 
 strentgth of EM wave 1, EM1f = frequency of EM wave 1
*)

sw = 38; sh = 4; gw = 3; gh = 4; cw = 6; sl = 7 gw + 6 cw;
grating = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.917, 0.082, 0.478],
    Cuboid[{{0, 0, sh}, {sw, gw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, gw + cw, sh}, {sw, 2 gw + cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 2 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 3 gw + 2 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 3 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 4 gw + 3 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 4 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 5 gw + 4 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 5 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 6 gw + 5 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 6 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 7 gw + 6 cw, sh + gh}}]}, 
   Boxed -> False];
slab = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.101, 0.701, 0.623],
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {sw, sl, sh}]}, Boxed -> False
   ];
EM1s = 1; EM1f = 3; x1 = 2 Pi;
pts1 = Table[{t (x1/(2 Pi)), -EM1s Sin[EM1f t (x1/(2 Pi))], 0}, {t, 0,
     2 Pi, 0.03}];
pts2 = {#, 0, -#2} & @@@ pts1;
EMw1 = Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.007],
    {RGBColor[0.439, 0.188, 0.627], Line[pts1]},
    {RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], Line[pts2]}, Thickness[0.002], 
    Line[{#, # {1, 0, 1}}] & /@ pts1[[;; ;; 3]], 
    RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], 
    Line[{#, # {1, 1, 0}}] & /@ pts2[[;; ;; 3]]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> {True, False, False}, 
   Ticks -> None, 
   AxesStyle -> 
    Directive[Thickness[0.0075], RGBColor[0.439, 0.188, 0.627]], 
   Boxed -> False];
Show[slab, grating, EMw1, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> {400, 520}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Checking the values of plot range  for the three graphics object:

```
 {AbsoluteOptions[slab, PlotRange], AbsoluteOptions[EMw1, PlotRange]}
```

you get

> ```
> {{PlotRange -> {{0., 38.}, {0., 57.}, {0., 4.}}}, {PlotRange -> {{0., 
>  6.27}, {-0.999974, 0.999999}, {-0.999999, 0.999974}}}}
> ```

Using this information, define the rescaling transform

```
 rscTr = RescalingTransform[{{0, 6.27}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {{0, 
38}, {-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}]
```

and rescale the data for `EMw1`:

```
 rescaledPts1 = rscTr[pts1]; rescaledPts2 = rscTr[pts2];
```

and redraw your `EMw1` with rescaled data:

```
 rescaledEMw1 = 
 Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.007], {RGBColor[0.439, 0.188, 0.627], 
 Line[rescaledPts1]}, {RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], 
 Line[rescaledPts2]}, Thickness[0.002], 
 Line[{#, # {1, 0, 1}}] & /@ rescaledPts1[[;; ;; 3]], 
  RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], 
 Line[{#, # {1, 1, 0}}] & /@ rescaledPts2[[;; ;; 3]]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> {True, False, False}, 
 Ticks -> None, 
 AxesStyle -> 
 Directive[Thickness[0.0075], RGBColor[0.439, 0.188, 0.627]], 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 520}]
```

Now,

```
 Show[slab, grating, rescaledEMw1]
```

gives

[image: pict1]

The same output from a different viewpoint:

[image: pict2]

**EDIT: Alternative approach:** Define corrdinates of the slab and grating directly. I use a modification of [R.M.`s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/want-to-plot-a-plane-em-wave-but-neither-filling-axis-nor-edgeform-work) to OP's previous question, and specify the coordinates of the slab and grating objects.

First, slab and grating objects with modified coordinates:

```
 sw = 4 Pi; sh = .5; gw = .5; gh = .5; cw = 1.; sl = 9 gw + 8 cw; 
 grating =  Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.917, 0.082, 0.478], Opacity[.3], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 0, 0}, {sw, gw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, gw + cw, 0}, {sw, 2 gw + cw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 2 (gw + cw), 0}, {sw, 3 gw + 2 cw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 3 (gw + cw), 0}, {sw, 4 gw + 3 cw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 4 (gw + cw), 0}, {sw, 5 gw + 4 cw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 5 (gw + cw), 0}, {sw, 6 gw + 5 cw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 6 (gw + cw), 0}, {sw, 7 gw + 6 cw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 7 (gw + cw), 0}, {sw, 8 gw + 7 cw, gh}}], 
 Cuboid[{{0, 8 (gw + cw), 0}, {sw, 9 gw + 8 cw, gh}}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 520}];
 slab = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.101, 0.701, 0.623], Opacity[.5], 
 Cuboid[{0, 0, -.5}, {4 Pi, 4 Pi, 0}]}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 520}];
```

Next, a modifed version of R.M.`s waves (replicating the pair of waves four times):

```
  Module[{w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, colors, plot, lines}, 
  w1[x_] := {x, 0, Sin[x]}; w2[x_] := {x, Sin[x], 0}; 
  w3[x_] := {4 \[Pi], x, Sin[x]}; w4[x_] := {4 \[Pi] + Sin[x], x, 0}; 
  w5[x_] := {x, 4 \[Pi], -Sin[x - Pi]}; 
  w6[x_] := {x, 4 \[Pi] - Sin[x - Pi], 0}; w7[x_] := {0, x, Sin[x]}; 
  w8[x_] := {Sin[x], x, 0};
  colors =   Darker /@ {Blue, Orange, Blue, Orange, Blue, Orange, Blue, Orange};
  {plot, lines} = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{w1[x], w2[x], w3[x], w4[x], w5[x], w6[x], w7[x], 
   w8[x]}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> {{-Pi, 5 Pi}, {-Pi, 5 Pi}, {-2, 2}}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Thick, Thick, Thick, Thick, Thick, Thick, 
    Thick}, colors}\[Transpose], 
  EvaluationMonitor :> 
  Sow[{Line[{w1[x], {x, 0, 0}}], Line[{w2[x], {x, 0, 0}}], 
   Line[{w3[x], {4 \[Pi], x, 0}}], Line[{w4[x], {4 \[Pi], x, 0}}],
    Line[{w5[x], {x, 4 \[Pi], 0}}], 
   Line[{w6[x], {x, 4 \[Pi], 0}}], Line[{w7[x], {0, x, 0}}], 
   Line[{w8[x], {0, x, 0}}]}]] // Reap; 
  GraphicsRow[{Show[plot, 
  Graphics3D[Insert[Flatten[lines, 1], colors, 1]\[Transpose]], 
  ViewPoint -> {3.009, -1.348, 0.759}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0.406, -0.398, 5.732}, Ticks -> None, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.75], 
  Show[plot, slab, grating, 
  Graphics3D[Insert[Flatten[lines, 1], colors, 1]\[Transpose]], 
  ViewPoint -> {3.009, -1.348, 0.759}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0.406, -0.398, 5.732}, Ticks -> None, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.75]}, ImageSize -> 900]]
```

Two views of the resulting 3D graphs:

[image: view 1]

[image: view 2]

Comment: This solves my scaling problem but does not "detach" the two objects.  Is there a way to move the wave away from the x-axis of the slab?

Comment: @RainforestFrog, I think it can be done by translating the data for the two waves in `y` and `z` directions. There may be more direct ways to do it, but one manual way is to play with several parameter values for the transformation inside a `Manipulate`. I will try to put together a `Manipulate` example in a day or so.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help received, especially to kguler.  My solution is probably the most cumbersome, but it works.
*sw = slab width, sh = slab height, gw = grid width, gh = 
 grid height, cw = channel width, sl = slab length, EM1s = 
 strentgth of EM wave 1, EM1f = frequency of EM wave 1, EM2s = 
 strength of EM wave 2, EM2f = frequency of EM wave 2*

*SLAB, GRATING*

```
sw = 60; sh = 6; gw = 4; gh = 6; cw = 9; sl = 8 gw + 7 cw;
grating = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.917, 0.082, 0.478],
    Cuboid[{{0, 0, sh}, {sw, gw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, gw + cw, sh}, {sw, 2 gw + cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 2 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 3 gw + 2 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 3 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 4 gw + 3 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 4 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 5 gw + 4 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 5 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 6 gw + 5 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 6 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 7 gw + 6 cw, sh + gh}}],
    Cuboid[{{0, 7 (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, 8 gw + 7 cw, sh + gh}}]}, 
   Boxed -> False];
slab = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.101, 0.701, 0.623],
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {sw, sl, sh}]}, Boxed -> False
   ];
```

*WAVE1*

```
EM1s = 1; EM1f = 3; x1 = 2 Pi;
EM1pts1 = 
  Table[{t (x1/(2 Pi)), -EM1s Sin[EM1f t (x1/(2 Pi))], 0}, {t, 0, 
    2 Pi, 0.03}];
EM1pts2 = {#, 0, -#2} & @@@ EM1pts1;
rscTr1 = RescalingTransform[{{0., 6.27}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}, {{0., 
     38.}, {-8., 8.}, {-8., 8.}}];
EM1rescaledPts1 = rscTr1[EM1pts1]; EM1rescaledPts2 = rscTr1[EM1pts2];
nEMw1 = {Thickness[0.007], {RGBColor[0.439, 0.188, 0.627], 
    Line[EM1rescaledPts1]}, {RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], 
    Line[EM1rescaledPts2]}, Thickness[0.002], 
   Line[{#, # {1, 0, 1}}] & /@ EM1rescaledPts1[[;; ;; 3]], 
   RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], 
   Line[{#, # {1, 1, 0}}] & /@ EM1rescaledPts2[[;; ;; 3]]};
tEMw1 = {Translate[nEMw1, {{-25, 48, 30}}]};
trEMw1 = Graphics3D[Rotate[tEMw1, 30 Degree, {0, 1, 0}]];
```

*WAVE2*

```
EM2s = 1; EM2f = 1; x2 = 4 Pi;
EM2pts1 = 
  Table[{t (x2/(2 Pi)), -EM2s Sin[EM2f t (x2/(2 Pi))], 0}, {t, 0, 
    2 Pi, 0.03}];
EM2pts2 = {#, 0, -#2} & @@@ EM2pts1;
rscTr2 = RescalingTransform[{{0., 6.27}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}, {{0., 
     38.}, {-8., 8.}, {-8., 8.}}];
EM2rescaledPts1 = rscTr2[EM2pts1]; EM2rescaledPts2 = rscTr2[EM2pts2];
nEMw2 = {Thickness[0.007], {RGBColor[0.498, 0.819, 0.231], 
    Line[EM2rescaledPts1]},
   {RGBColor[0.917, 0.082, 0.478], Line[EM2rescaledPts2]}, 
   Thickness[0.002], 
   Line[{#, # {1, 0, 1}}] & /@ EM2rescaledPts1[[;; ;; 3]], 
   RGBColor[0.917, 0.082, 0.478], 
   Line[{#, # {1, 1, 0}}] & /@ EM2rescaledPts2[[;; ;; 3]]};
tEMw2 = {Translate[nEMw2, {{40, 48, -5}}]};
trEMw2 = Graphics3D[Rotate[tEMw2, -30 Degree, {0, 1, 0}]];

Show[slab, grating, trEMw1, trEMw2, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> {400, 520}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I am still working on making it look better, but currently it looks like something like the following.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Rotate`, `Scale` and `Translate` to position the wave. By using `Manipulate` you can play around with the positioning until you're happy, and then post a screenshot using the option button in the upper right corner of the panel.

```
sw = 38; sh = 4; gw = 3; gh = 4; cw = 6; sl = 7 gw + 6 cw;
grating = 
  Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor[0.917, 0.082, 0.478],
    Table[
     Cuboid[{{0, i (gw + cw), sh}, {sw, (i + 1) gw + i cw, sh + gh}}],
     {i, 0, 6}]
   }, Boxed -> False];
slab = Graphics3D[{RGBColor[0.101, 0.701, 0.623], 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {sw, sl, sh}]}, Boxed -> False];
EM1s = 1; EM1f = 3; x1 = 2 Pi;
pts1 = Table[{t (x1/(2 Pi)), -EM1s Sin[EM1f t (x1/(2 Pi))], 0}, {t, 0,
     2 Pi, 0.03}];
pts2 = {#, 0, -#2} & @@@ pts1;
EMw1 = Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.007], {RGBColor[0.439, 0.188, 0.627], 
     Line[pts1]}, {RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], Line[pts2]}, 
    Thickness[0.002], Line[{#, # {1, 0, 1}}] & /@ pts1[[;; ;; 3]], 
    RGBColor[1, 0.721, 0.039], 
    Line[{#, # {1, 1, 0}}] & /@ pts2[[;; ;; 3]]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> {True, False, False}, 
   Ticks -> None, 
   AxesStyle -> 
    Directive[Thickness[0.0075], RGBColor[0.439, 0.188, 0.627]], 
   Boxed -> False];

Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{vec, rot, cr},
  vec = {Cos[phi] Sin[theta], Sin[phi] Sin[theta], Cos[theta]};
  cr = Cross[{1, 0, 0}, vec];
  If[N[Norm[Normalize[cr]]] === 0., cr = {0, 0, 1}];
  rot = {0, Sin[roll], Cos[roll]};
  Show[slab, grating, Graphics3D[Translate[Scale[
      Rotate[Rotate[EMw1[[1]], roll, {1, 0, 0}],
       VectorAngle[{1, 0, 0}, vec], cr, { x1/2, 0, 0}], 
      scale  sw x1/(2 Pi)^2, {0, 0, 0}], {sw, sl, sw } {x, y, z}]], 
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> {400, 520}, 
   PlotRange -> All]],
 {{roll, 0}, -Pi, Pi},
 {{phi, 0}, -Pi, Pi},
 {{theta, Pi/2}, 0, Pi},
 {{x, 0}, -1, 1},
 {y, 0, 1},
 {z, 0, 1},
 {{scale, 1}, 0.1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]