# Including two ListLinePlots in a 3D graphic

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics3d

I have two lists of data which I am plotting on two `ListLinePlots`. I would like to have these two plots appear perpendicular to each other on a 3D graphic. I have tried to do this using a modification to the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/how-do-i-plot-a-plane-em-wave), but I am quite new to *Mathematica* so I had some trouble converting this into code that works for me.

Is there any way that I can implement this method when the data is lists rather than functions of some variable?

Comment: please include your code and some sample data. In short, yes, you can do it. The trick is to not plot it as `ListLinePlot`s, but to do a 3D line plot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a `ListLinePlot`, you're creating a 2D graphics. What you need to do is to take your 2D list data and plot it in 3D, with an appropriate value chosen for the third coordinate to make them perpendicular. Since you pointed to the EM wave example, I'll demonstrate an example using lists, that partially reproduces [my answer there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2007/5):

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 5 π, π/20}];
ListPointPlot3D[
    {
        data /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0}, 
        data /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, 0, y}
    }, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    Boxed -> False, Ticks -> None, AxesStyle -> LightGray
] /. Point -> Line
```

[image]