# Strange 3D plot behavior

Tags: plotting

**Two Part Question**

Part 1: As you can see from the data and plot below, the plot does not accurately display the data sets but adds lines beyond and in different dimensions.  Both u and v datasets are in {0,1} range, but v doesn't plot correctly.  Why this strange behavior? What did I miss here?

Part 2: How can I fill the lines to the Axis to make a 3D form from the correctly plotted lines making a more elegant looking plot? Thanks!

```
u = {{0, -0.44331262664448756`}, {0.0196`, -0.9779703843580401`},{0.0392`, -0.761419676160835`}, 
{0.0588`, -0.7410082141786067`},{0.0784`, -1.1337733424705565`}, {0.102`, -1.0486362396635585`},
{0.149`, -0.2251024797836343`}, {0.2`, -1.2871097065127457`},{0.251`, -0.9511305495415456`}, 
{0.302`, -0.8164066459261932`},{0.349`, -0.7856901292758733`}, {0.4`, -0.8996334304312015`},
{0.451`, -0.6566406380705825`}, {0.498`, -0.27392146117227734`},{0.549`, -0.2943716563989507`},
{0.6`, -0.005103507205728164`}, {0.651`, 0.1514427552803399`}, {0.698`, 0.5919523857004505`}, 
{0.749`, 1.485852053899006`}, {0.8`, 1.1930387245891183`}, {0.851`, 0.771890328176178`}, 
{0.898`, 0.13245346840587424`}, {0.949`, -0.06005129796635145`}, {0.9804`,-0.6909201620317884`},
 {1, -2.886054510422592`}};

v = {{0, 1.7277993371975775`}, {0.0196`,0.7046147676309067`}, {0.0392`,-0.14324752873255964`}, 
{0.0588`,-0.278024151638645`}, {0.0784`, -0.2257145006115291`}, {0.102`,-0.8323709054502082`}, 
{0.149`, -0.0840232633295912`}, {0.2`,-0.8432031344867141`}, {0.251`, -1.052961606965508`}, 
{0.302`,-1.0016400464038844`}, {0.349`, -0.47166441886878907`}, {0.4`,-0.5634900663427977`}, 
{0.451`, -0.8219157180967107`}, {0.498`,-0.599958880780993`}, {0.549`, -0.1889940612199048`}, 
{0.6`,-0.3952379660987937`}, {0.651`, -0.26706893123602526`}, {0.698`,0.5833238256280904`},
 {0.749`, 0.9884089479900493`}, {0.8`, 0.721317446974723`}, {0.851`,-0.07891186493267366`}, 
{0.898`, -1.202139489716314`}, {0.949`, -1.4943329078699996`}, {0.9804`,-2.3465771005766967`}, 
{1, -2.852635384504043`}};

results = ListPointPlot3D[{v /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0}, u}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange},AxesOrigin -> 
{0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1}, Ticks -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> Black, 
PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 280] /. Point -> Line
```

[image: 3D Plot Error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are plotting is:

```
 v /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0}, u}
```

If you look at this, it is a collection of points in 3D followed by a collection of points in 2D. You need o have purely a list of 3D points in order for `ListPointPlot3D` to work. For example,

```
{v /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 0}, u /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, 1}}
```

will work fine, putting v on one plane and u on another.

[image]

But looking back, maybe what you are after is to take the first two coordinates from v and the third from u? If so, you can do that by plotting

```
q = Table[{v[[i, 1]], v[[i, 2]], u[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length[v]}];
```

which gives a nice squiggle

[image]

But in any case, the point is that you have to plot a list of 3D points in order to make use of `ListPointPlot3D`. In the comments, the OP gave a link to the kind of plot he wanted. Here is how to do exactly that same thing here, and I've even added in part 2 about how to get the filling:

```
results =  ListPointPlot3D[{v /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0}, 
                u /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, 0, y}}, 
         PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange}, Filling -> Axis, 
         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1}, 
         Ticks -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, 
         ImageSize -> 280] /. Point -> Line
```

This time it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution although it's not quite what I'm after.  My implementation is based on the answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23362/including-two-listlineplots-in-a-3d-graphic/23364#23364  Where this type of plot actually does work well.  In fact it does work when combined with a second plot in Show[] but not individually.

Comment: In that reference, the data has the form of 3-tuples. The data you are trying to plot does not have that form. That's why it fails.

Comment: ah I see that now! Thanks!

Comment: How do I fill both lines?

Comment: There might be a slick way, but here's what I'd do: graph a third function that is just the axis you want to fill to. Then you can fill from object i to object p (see Details section in the Filling help). This provides a completely general solution.

Comment: thanks for your help!